# Problem in delimiting a limit for a loop. Euler problem 5

Tags: javascript, math

> I have a question, my code worked but in the case that it's a bigger number and I don't have an idea of where to put the limit in my i position... How can I optimize this code, so I don't need to calculate the limit and not put so many zeros in my i? Or there's no way and this is as it should be?

```
        function prob5(){
        for(var i =1;i<10000000000;i++){
            if((i%1)==0 && (i%2)==0 && (i%3)==0 && (i%4)==0 && (i%5)==0 && (i%6)==0 && (i%7)==0 && (i%8)==0 && (i%9)==0 && (i%10)==0 && (i%11)==0 && (i%12)==0 && (i%13)==0 && (i%14)==0 && (i%15)==0 && (i%16)==0 && (i%17)==0 && (i%18)==0 && (i%19)==0 && (i%20)==0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        console.log(i);
    }
```

Comment: 20 factorial is 1*2*3*...*20 so it is guaranteed to be divisible by 1 through 20.

Comment: @RockySims: But the idea is to find the *smallest* positive integer divisible by 1 through 20.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you just return 20! I'm suggesting that 20! is a good limit (to replace 10000000000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getLowestNumDivisibleByAllUpTo(limit) {
  const numMax = factorial(limit);
  for (let num = 1; num < numMax; num++) {
    let divisibleByAll = true;
    for (let divisor = 2; divisor <= limit; divisor++) {
      if (num % divisor !== 0) {
        divisibleByAll = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (divisibleByAll) {
      return num;
    }
  }
}

function factorial(n) {
  if (n < 2) return 1;
  return n * factorial(n - 1);
}

console.log(getLowestNumDivisibleByAllUpTo(20));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*
the number you are looking for is called the least common multiple (lcm)
to find the least common multiple of all numbers in an array:
compute the lcm of the first two, then the lcm of the fist two with the third and so on
lcm(2,3)=6, lcm(6,4)=12, lcm(12,5)=60, etc
the following is much more efficient because it doesn't search billions of numbers
to check if they are divisible by 2 and 3 and 4 and ... 20
it just applies the same function, lcm, 18 times
*/

const limit = 20;
const divisors = [...Array(limit - 1)].map((v, i) => 2 + i);
// greatest common divisor of two numbers
const gcd = (a, b) => b ? gcd(b, a % b) : Math.abs(a);
// least common multiple of two numbers
const lcm = (a, b) => a * b / gcd(a, b);
// least common multiple of all numbers in an array
const lcma = array => array.reduce(lcm);
console.log(lcma(divisors));
```